# In Google Cloud, why would a Compute Engine instance need Service Control and Service Management APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In the process of reviewing some GCP inventory, I've noticed a Compute Engine (CE) instance has the following API accesses:

```
Service Control     Enabled
Service Management  Read Only
```

The code running on the CE instance doesn't interact with the GCP platform itself.

Are these APIs required for the CE instance to run?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Scopes limit the permissions that the Compute Engine service account has. Compute Engine itself does not use these permissions except for special configurations. Your applications running inside Compute Engine do. Example apps running inside Compute Engine that need permission is Cloud Logging (the Stackdriver Scopes). Review what permissions (roles) your apps require and enable those scopes. Note: Scopes are an old legacy authorization method. Today, enable all scopes and control permissions via IAM Roles.

Comment: @JohnHanley I understand scopes and how to assign them to service accounts, etc.. I'm a bit unsure what those 2 specific APIs do for a CE instance.

Comment: Compute Engine does not require or use any of the listed scopes to operate. You can disable all scopes. It is the software inside the VM that might require certain features.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, that's kind of what i was thinking but didn't want to break VM functionality

Comment: Two items that you should enable are Stackdriver so that logging and monitoring continue to function.

Comment: @JohnHanley Maybe had this summary as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to run a Compute Engine instance without the [Service Control](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-control/reference/rest) and [Service Management](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest) APIs accesses, however for the Google Cloud Endpoints those accesses are required, [reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts?&_ga=2.32426423.-844666523.1620838637#associating_a_service_account_to_an_instance).

Comment: I guess shifting the question.. in which condition would a CE instance requires access to Google Cloud Endpoints?